# ASP.NET User Controls or Master Page or other for Data Entry Form

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, user-controls, master-pages

I'm building a data entry form for order processing and could use some best practice advice.  If there is a more elegant way to do what I've outlined here in ASP.NET and I'm not seeing it, I just wanted to reach out for opinions.

I have an old application that I'm modeling a new one after.  So this is a brand-new design.

I have an order entry page(s) to write.   In my situation , an order consists of:
* a header area, with merchant and customer shipping information
* a detail area with line items displayed on it as the user adds them from a menu

I have four order types that will use this same layout but the business logic behind them all will be different.

So my question is this.

What would be the best way, in someone's opinion to accomplish this without duplicating the page layouts four times and still keeping the differing business logic separate?

I've considered making the control areas into user controls, then creating an order page for each type of order I need, and writing business logic for each page.  That's where I'm headed in my design.

However, if there is a best practice or more elegant way that I'm overlooking; I could really use the advice.

Thanks very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MasterPages are good when the *layout* is common across pages.  User Controls are useful for smaller pieces of reusable components.

From what you have described, I would use a MasterPage for the order page layout.  Then create 4 order pages (that use this MasterPage) and inherit from a base page class.  You could place a submit order button on the Master and then handle it on each of the order pages.  If there are any common components (other than layout) on each order page, such as a list of order items, you could use a User Control for these.

```
public abstract class OrderPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         this.Master.SubmitButton.Click += new EventHandler(SubmitButton_Click);
     }

     protected override void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         CalculateTotal();
         SubmitOrder();
     }

     protected abstract void CalculateTotal();
     protected abstract void SubmitOrder();
}

public partial class OrderType1Page : OrderPage
{
     protected override void CalculateTotal() {
        ...
     }

     protected override void SubmitOrder() {
        ...
     }
}

public partial class OrderType2Page : OrderPage
{
     protected override void CalculateTotal() {
        ...
     }

     protected override void SubmitOrder() {
        ...
     }
}

...
```

Comment: Thanks!  I do have the exact same layout for each order.  Common functionality (like for the control grouping at the top of each page) sounds like it would work out to be a user-control then.  That was where I was headed - just needed a second opinion to make sure I wasn't too close to the code to see the trees!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A user control will provide more flexability for use on pages that don't all share the same exact layout. Sometimes it is hard to layout a MasterPage in such a manner that the containers on it allow for full customization. As a user control you could include it on the page or in the MasterPage and share that same common code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I am fortunate enough to have a common layout so it sounds like the MasterPage would be the way to go.  Thanks again!